# CSS / JQuery Horizontal menu with 2 line

Tags: jquery, css, menu

[image: a busy cat]

I created a menu with jquery: div 1 for a main menu and div 2 for the submenu.
When you hover the mouse over the item, the div 2 appears under the selected menu.

Can I make a menu more optimized?

Can you make a CSS menu on 2 lines with the function described in the image?

```
<div id="main-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="category" rel="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="category" rel="submenu1">test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="menu-wrap">
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="submenu1" class="submenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">sub menu 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

is possible to realize the menu without the use of jquery but only CSS?

Comment: So where is the markup you have tried so far.

Comment: You could leave the dom of the submenu but hide it when you go to another menulist, just append the new menu behond it, then whena already loaded part has to be shown you only have to set the vissibility to vissible, this way you are a bit faster but you also use a bit more memory

Comment: can you post the code you have done so far

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, the sub-menus will need to be nested (in the DOM) inside of their main-menu entries. We'll need to modify the HTML markup using lists.

A description of the code: we'll create a container for the whole thing, and float that right. After the container, we'll have a div that simply clears the float, so the rest of the page displays properly. Inside of the container, we'll have an unordered list for the main menu -- each list item will contain a link and an unordered list for the submenus. Those submenu lists will initially be `display:none`. We'll have to position the submenus absolutely, so that they appear below below the main menu instead of in the middle. Then the magic happens using the `:hover` pseudo selector, and a nested selection: when a main-menu list item is hovered, it's child `ul` tag will be set to `display:block`.

HTML changes:

```
<div id="menu-container">
    <ul id="main-menu">
        <li> <a href="#">Home</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Menu Item 1</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 1 Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Menu Item 2</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 2 Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Menu Item 3</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Submenu 3 Item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
```

And the accompanying CSS:

```
#menu-container {
    float:right;
}
#main-menu {
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
}
.submenu {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:1em;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}
#main-menu, .submenu {
    list-style:none;
}
#main-menu li, .submenu li {
    display:inline;
}
#main-menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

See the live demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/t42Lyj2o/).

This may need some tweaking to support legacy browsers, if that is a requirement. Some code (for hover effect) was sourced from the [A List Apart Suckerfish CSS Dropdown Menu](http://alistapart.com/article/dropdowns).

Comment: an alternative to the `#main-menu li:hover ul` selector would be `#main-menu li a:hover + ul` (if you prefer to hover the links rather than list-items). this uses the adjacency selector and may have a more narrow browser support.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) The submenu item are not aligned in the center than to the father item - http://jsfiddle.net/ggrwLs0r/2/

Comment: i've popped in an edit that should fix it (for `.submenu`, i changed `left:0` and added `width:100%`). if you find my solution suitable, i'd appreciate if you click the checkmark to mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Thank you! The child element is not aligned in the center respect the active element. http://i61.tinypic.com/2nu3ok3.jpg