# Making a navbar with two tiers and dropdown go horizontal at second tier

Tags: html, css, navbar

So, basically, i have a navbar. I want a second "navbar" beneath, which is always visible, but without users interaction, it displays nothing. But, when you hover over a tab in the main bar, a dropdown bar starts at a given point, and goes horizontally along the second tier.

This is my bar so far, and i know generally how to make a dropdown-bar, but i figured it would be easier for you to explain to me from this point, instead of telling me what to remove aswell.

http://jsfiddle.net/7yrX7/119/

```
<div id="nav">
<div id="container">
    <ul>        
    <li><img src="bilder/menu.jpg" style="height:120%; padding-left: 100px">    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> Left thing </a></li>
     <li>
    <a href="#"> Right thing </a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="bilder/facebook.ico" style=" height:100%; float:right; padding-right:50px;"> </a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com"><img src="bilder/twitter.ico" style=" height:100%; float:right; padding-right: 15px;"></a>
</div>
</div>

<div id="ribbon">
</div>





body,
#nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
body { 
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 17px;
}

#nav {
    background: linear-gradient(#999C92,#72776A); 
    width: 100%;
    position:fixed;
    height:50px;

}
#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size:0; /*hack for inline-block removes side margins*/ 
}

#nav ul a{
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav > ul { text-align:center; } 

#nav li {

    font-size: 17px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

#nav li a{
padding: 15px;
display: block;
    display:inline-block;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color:red;
}

#nav a:visited { 
    color: white; 
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    float:left;
}
#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav a li a:hover {
    color: #699;
}



#ribbon {
width: 100%;
height: 20px;
background-color: black;

}
```

Comment: i just gave an answer to a very similar question over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25623012/css-jquery-horizontal-menu-with-2-line/25623737). it would only take a little bit of tweaking to get it working for you.

Comment: I have dropdown bars, i have them going horizontal and right size etc. The problem is that i want the dropdown bars to be displayed in the middle of a already visible second bar, laying beneath the already existing navbar. I also want every dropdown to start at a spesific place, so that if i have multiple dropdown tabs, they all start at the same, for example to the far left.

Comment: I managed to get the tabs displayed at the far left, as i wanted. So, the only problem then, is to have the background bar always visible. Also, now the background bar is connected to the tabs and not the other way around, meaning that if i want to have the dropdowns be displayed some px to the right of the bar, the bar would follow.. any solution?

Comment: can you post updated code or an updated jsfiddle? i'm having trouble visualizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am basing this fix off of the updated code you posted as an "answer" (in the future, you can update your question instead by using the edit feature).

The trick to getting a persistent bar to display below the main navigation is just to add some div to the end (let's call it `ribbon_filler`) and make it always visible. When the dropdown appears, it just appears above the ribbon filler. Here's an example of what the CSS for the filler might look like:

```
#ribbon_filler {
  top:50px;
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #ACD661;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

You can see this used in your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5qxc32fd/).

Answer (score 0):

I would look into an implementation of Superfish which is a great jQuery menu and gives you more than you are likely to develop on your own.

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/examples/#